# Is it possible to call an action from an XDocument XElement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am generating a calendar using XDocument in .NET Core and passing it to a view as a tag helper.

I would like to make each day clickable and pass the date of each day as an Id to an action in another controller. Is this possible using XDocument or can it only generate raw HTML?

What I would like to do ideally is something like this: `@Html.ActionLink("", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { date = d })` for each day.

I have tried wrapping the `<div>` with `class="day"` in an `<a>` XAttribute with `d` as the `href` - that turns the day clickable and passes the DateTime in the URL but I can't work out how to call a specific action.

```
var startDate = monthStart.AddDays(-(int)monthStart.DayOfWeek);
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 42).Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i));

foreach (var d in dates)
{
    if (d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday && d != startDate)
    {
        yield return new XElement("div",
            new XAttribute("class", "w-100"),
            String.Empty
        );
    }

    var mutedClasses = "d-none d-inline-block bg-light text-muted";
    yield return new XElement("div",
        new XAttribute("class", $"day col p-2 border-top-0 text-truncate {(d.Month != monthStart.Month ? mutedClasses : null)}"),
        new XElement("h6",
            new XAttribute("class", "row align-items-center"),
            new XElement("span",
                new XAttribute("class", "date col-1"),
                d.Day
            ),
            new XElement("span",
                new XAttribute("class", "col-1"),
                String.Empty
            )
        ),
        GetEventHtml(d)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using the [LinkGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
public class CalendarTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;

    public CalendarTagHelper(LinkGenerator linkGenerator)
    {
        _linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
    }
```

Then call this method in the `href` of the `a` XElement passing `d` as a parameter:

```
    private string GetDayUrl(DateTime date)
    {
        return _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("Day", "Home", values: {date = date});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code is in a controller, you can set the href of the anchor by calling the Url property of controllerbase (implementing an IUrlHelper)

eg: new XAttribute("href", Url("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { date = d }))

Comment: Thanks for responding. This code is in a separate class that inherits TagHelper, is there a way to call the Url property outside of a controller or view?